# Why is this pointer program not overwriting all the RAM memory location?

Tags: c, pointers

This is the code I wrote to overwrite the RAM data and eventually leading in crashing the OS.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
    int i=10;
    int *j;
    j=&i;   
    int m=0;
    while(true){
        *(j+m)=m*m; //next location of i
        printf("New Value is. %d \n",(m));       
        m++;
    }
    printf("Complete");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But the only after m is 46 my program is crashing(the value of m can be different from compiler to compiler).
Why this program is behaving in such manner? Is it because our OS provides some fixed space of memory to load & run a program and overreaching the memory limit would cause crashing the program?

Comment: yes, the OS protects your program from accessing data that doesn't belong to it. Hence you won't ever write to other program's or the OS's memory.

Comment: Which environment or Operating System are you running on?  OS's like Windows and Linux don't normally give you access to RAM, only to Virtual Memory, which spends much of its time on disk.  The size of the Virtual Address Space accessible to the user depends on the OS design, the word size (e.g. 32/64 bit), and so on.  Both Windows and Linux have a "guard region" to give some protection against low address pointers.  Note this is an address range - not a real memory area.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The unclear sentence is: "But the only after m is 46 my program is crashing". What is it that surprises you: that it takes so many iterations to see the program crash, or that it's just the program that crashes, instead of the full OS (which you said is your intention)?

Comment: Firstly, in any modern desktop OS your program will not have access to RAM. It can only access its own virtual address space. So, your belief that you are somehow "accessing RAM" here is competely unfounded. Secondly, you are not allowed to freely and randomly access even your own virtual address space. The very moment you hit a write-protected region of your address space, your program will typically crash.

Comment: @FabioTurati I thought that it will access all the way to my last memory location of my RAM. But as some of you clarified that it will be loaded in virtual memory not in RAM then it should go the last memory location of virtual memory if os allows(that was my question whether OS itself restricts or it is some other issue)

Comment: @AnuragChakraborty:  pages in your address space do not all have write access.  First the page has to be allocated.  You have `malloc` but that only allocates memory on the heap.  If the page is, for example, a code page then it will (should) be write-protected.  On Windows there are ways around that, but the protection is there for good reason.  You appear to have a very simplistic view of computer memory, I suggest you do further research.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the stack, destroying data from local variables and return from procedure pointers from your current function through all other functions called before it, until you reach a part of memory that is read-only because it contains the actual code of your program, and this part is protected. When you try to overwrite that too, the system will prevent it and the application will crash with a "Memory cannot be written" error of something like that.

Not sure about Linux, but in Windows you can disprotect this memory with `VirtualProtect()`. But doing that will only make it crash a little down the road as you overwrite the loop code with garbage and die in a Segmentation Fault error.

But still, you won't have access to the actual RAM of your computer, you can't even know the actual address in the real RAM you are in. When you are a process under a operational system, you are in the realm of virtual memory, where the OS will guarantee you cannot interfer directly with the system's or other processes' memory, not without going through the channels the system offers you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, after the very first iteration, `*(j+m)` is invalid memory access, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Then, nothing, absolutely nothing is guaranteed.

In *your* case, it just happens that until index 46, the memory location is accessible from the process (i.e, the location belongs to the process's [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), though that does not mean you are allowed to access, you may be overwriting some other data) and past that index, the memory location is not accessible from your process, so the access violation happens, causing the segfault.

Comment: Did you miss ` j=&i; `?

Comment: @WeatherVane well, it appears that the memory location was accessible from the process (maybe overwriting some other data), but you never know.

Comment: Looks as if it is the stack being overwritten, since `i` is a local variable.

Comment: "nothing, absolutely nothing is guaranteed." --> do you _guarantee_ that or is that a [rabbit hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning)? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Understand one thing first... Accessing a block of memory that was not initially defined  leads to undefined behavior according to the rules of C language!

Now undefined behavior is seriously not undefined. In my case when I run the program, it crashes only after m=1.

There is no logic behind defining the sense of undefined. Undefined behavior may not only depend upon what causes it but several other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that you program contains an undefined behavior because you tried to access memory you didn't allocate in some way, what you observe is some *protection* ensured by OS your program is running on.

It is very common for OS to manage space allocated to running programs by chunks of space. Such a chunk is usually called a **page**. A **page** is the finer grain of memory an OS can manage on behalf the process. So even if accessing the next memory address of variable `i` is logically false (*undefined behavior*), the generated code for the machine probably obviously try to get the memory content. At that time OS/CPU/MMU only verify if that address is in a page of your process. So the crash appears only when you access a page that is not in the space of your process.

If you want more details, read about **virtual memory**, **page fault**...